# Using span inside View code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I am getting this error of CS0201 in my MVC View Index.cshtml. I have also use @using System.Web.Mvc.Html. How to correctly write  and use insede variable...

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Source Error:

```
Line 78:  <div class="pagesize">
Line 79:         @Html.Repeat(new[] { 5, 10, 20, 40 }, ps =>
Line 80:         {
Line 81:         if (ps == Model.Search.PageSize)
Line 82:         {
Line 83:             @<span>@ps</span>;
Line 84:         }
Line 85:         else
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: as a starter, you can try removing the @ sign before `<span>`

Comment: It underline all row "<span>@ps</span>" with red with this error; "Cannot symbol span"

Comment: the last i can help is to try wrapping this inside a text tag :) like so:

`<text><span>@ps</span></text>`

Comment: It did not help, still underline @ps inside span with this line: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: please accept my apologies. its quiet late here and cannot try to test locally .. apologies again :)

Comment: No problem, realy thanks for help, I will continue trying...